# why is this visual studios file not compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio

so I'm a bit new to c++/windows.h programming and I am in the middle of learning basic functions like how to create a window....and I tried to run this code (in visual studio 2022)that was in microsoft as sort of an example code but it still wouldn't compile giving the error -

Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)   MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)

Here is the code I tried to run (its an unchanged example from microsoft of how to make a window)-

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);



        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I'd like to know how to fix this....thanx in advance

Comment: Is that the entire linker error?

Comment: there was also this part about  MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) that I edited in to the original question

Comment: If the answer helps please accept it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will help others with the same problem.

Comment: Hi, is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

1. `Create a new project-> Windows Desktop Wizard->Desktop Application`.

   **Check** `Empty  Project`.
2. Add a new  cpp file  and   copy your code.

Comment: when I try to do what you said I get this new massage saying that the system can't find the file specified....what do I do to fix that.....the old error isn't there anymore when I do that but like I said theres a new error now saying the system can't find the file specified....pls tell me how to fix this...thanx in advance

Comment: C++ workload may not be installed. Please make sure C++ is installed in VS installer.